# packagemanager.install error: PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_VIOLATION

Tags: deployment, certificate, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I want to install package from my application. For this i have to add packagemanager.install privilege. But when i try to run application i get an error:

Installing the package failed.

**Error code: PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_VIOLATION**

> Error message:  Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -i -q -t wgt -p
>   "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/inst.wgt" Management: Refer to Help contents >
>   Getting Started with Tizen > Overview > Privilege.

I am testing in device Gear(b8a5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with your signed certificate from Samsung not being present on your Gear device. You must follow the certification instructions at `Help > Help Contents > Getting Started with Tizen Wearable > Development Environment > Tizen SDK for Wearable > Certificates` to get a signed certificate with your Gear's DUID from Samsung.

If you have already followed these steps, it could be that you need to copy the certificate received from Samsung onto your device in the Tizen ide by selecting your debuggable device and navigating to `Home > Developer` and placing the certificate in there.

The certificate allows your app to be run on your physical device. It is removed from the device if you perform a factory reset.